# Generic class for this JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, data-modeling

I have a question which involves data modelling.

I have to develop two projects. which involves localization (Backend API, Frontend angular).

The purpose of the backend is to execute CRUD operations on a MongoDB instance, and the purpose of the frontend is to edit or create these localizations.

What is the best approach for modelling this data? As I want to create it so generic as possible.

Data:

```json
  "tabs": {
    "overview": "Overview",
    "schedule": "Schedule",
    "insights": "Insights",
    "settings": "Settings",
    "presets": "Presets"
  }
 "general": {
    "edit": Edit,
    "bluetooth" {
        "activate": "activation",
        "test": "testing"
     }
}
```

The data can contain objects in a objects. "bluetooth" example.
This data grows continously as it should contain every localization of a certain application. The example above is the first 14 rows of a file

I thought something like:

```
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, object> Translation { get; set; }
```

Is there a better alternative for this?

```
public string Category { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, object> Translation { get; set; }
```

Tried this but don't know if this is the best approach there is.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind is that the more generic a representation is, the more difficult it will be to use. So while the most *generic* representation would be `byte[]`, it is not a very *useful* representation.

If you want to parse an arbitrary json tree you can use System.Text.Json to do the parsing, and process the produced JsonNodes or JsonDocument however you wish. See [How to use a JSON document object model in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom). But code for this would tend to be rather convoluted.

If you *can* specify a specific type model that would almost certainly be better. Since you can just let the library convert the json to c# objects, and process the objects. The type model may include polymorphic types, trees, and in some cases even circular references, depending on the specific library and settings.

Answer (score 0):

First way is evil.

1. Just use `Newtonsoft.Json` and deserialzie to `dynamic` type, and ignore all type safety.

Second way is annoying, but technically correct

2. Using `System.Text.Json` you can make any class like this:

```cs
public class WeatherForecastWithExtensionData
{
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement>? ExtensionData { get; set; }
    //or:
    //public Dictionary<string, object>? ExtensionData { get; set; }

}
```

and all properties that were not hardcoded within the class will magically end in that dictionary.